# Invalid property 'messageService ' of bean class [Person]- Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring

I'm having this error while trying dependency injection with Spring Framework

> Invalid property 'messageService ' of bean class [Person]: Bean
>   property 'messageService ' is not writable or has an invalid setter
>   method. Did you mean 'messageService'?

Here's my class Person:

```
public class Person {
    private MessageService messageService;

    public void setMessageService(MessageService messageService){
          this.messageService  = messageService;
    }

    public MessageService getMessageService() {
          return this.messageService;
    }

    public void Chao(String Subject, String Message)
    {
        messageService.sendMessage(Subject,Message);
    }

}
```

Here's my Beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
   <bean id="email" class="Email"></bean>
   <bean id="Person" class="Person">
       <property name="messageService " ref="email"></property>
   </bean>
</beans>
```

And finally the Main class

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml"); 

        Person test = (Person) context.getBean("Person");
        test.Chao("abc","abc");
    }
}
```

`MessageService` is an interface, class `Email implements MessageService`
Can anybody tells me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a blank at the end of `name="messageService "`. please remove it.